# How to show two properties when filtering a list in Angular

Tags: angularjs, filter

I am trying to show two properties of an object. To do this, I am filtering from an array using another one of it's properties. I found a solution on here but it only works for a single property.

Here is a sample code

```
controller.js
$scope.people= [{name, last_name, code}, {name, last_name, code}];

view
<tr ng-repeat="item in transactions | filter:search">
  <td>{{(people| filter : {code:item.person_code}:true)[0].name}}</td>
</tr>
```

I want to be able to show not only the name but also the last_name. Separated by comma if possible.

Right now it works but I am only displaying the name and I don't know how to display more than one property.

Is this even possible???

Comment: in angular js 2 i do like <td> {{item.name}} : {{item.last_name}}</td>

Comment: @PranayRana same in ng1 :)

Comment: See this working Plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/sjUqjP74eiMnp5b4SIRq Does it fit with your need ?

Comment: That would be great if the information I have to display is in a different array that the one I am iterating on. I want to display a person's name and last name from the people's array... But the ng-repeat is used over the transactions' array. Item does not have the property name nor last_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store `filter`s result into `temp` variable and then use it to show desired properties:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in transactions | filter : search">
    <td ng-init='temp = (people | filter : {code:item.person_code}:true)[0]'>
         {{temp.name}} {{temp.last_name}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

Data:

```
$scope.people= [{name:"SUN", last_name:"SS", code:"101"}, 
 {name:"MOON", last_name:"MM", code:"103"},{name:"ION", 
 last_name:"IO", code:"105"}];
$scope.transactions= [{person_code:"105"}, {person_code:"103"}];
```

Filter:

```
filter('pFilter',function(){
return function(input,trans) {
var result =[];
angular.forEach(trans,function(item){
angular.forEach(input,function(p){
if(p.code == item.person_code)
result.push(p);
});
});
return result;
}
})
```

HTML:

```
   <input ng-model="search"/>
   <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="p in people | filter:search|pFilter:transactions ">
    <td>{{$index +1}}. {{p.name}}: {{p.last_name}}</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

Hope this works if data is big and you want to display more in table.